# HTTP filter - pass request based on subrequest response

Tags: c, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to implement filter module based on ngx_http_auth_request_module which will send (sub)request to another webserver and accept/reject the request based on response of that subrequest.

That subrequest has to use different method(POST), different URI then original request and JSON payload. This is a reason I can't use auth_request module in combination with proxy_pass.

Is there are way to send subrequest externally by using Nginx's subrequest structure/api? Seems like I am getting redirected internally only.

If not, I guess I will have to do something similar what proxy module does?

Thank you!